# cisco877w, не работает интернет через wifi

Tags: cisco

cisco877w
нужно настроить доступ wifi клиентам в интернет
подключаюсь по wifi, получаю адрес, пингуется 10.10.10.1 и внешний адрес Dialer0, но в интернет доступа через wifi нет. с самого роутера интернет доступен, пингуется
подскажите, как исправить

```
version 12.4
no service pad
service tcp-keepalives-in
service tcp-keepalives-out
service timestamps debug datetime msec localtime show-timezone
service timestamps log datetime msec localtime show-timezone
service password-encryption
service sequence-numbers
!
hostname myrouter
!
boot-start-marker
boot system tftp c870-advipservicesk9-mz.124-11.XJ.bin 10.10.10.103
boot-end-marker
!
logging buffered 51200
logging console critical
enable password 7 071C70310F1A0D5605
!
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa group server radius rad_eap
 server 127.0.0.1 auth-port 1645 acct-port 1646
!
aaa group server radius rad_mac
!
aaa group server radius rad_acct
!
aaa group server radius rad_admin
!
aaa group server tacacs+ tac_admin
!
aaa group server radius rad_pmip
!
aaa group server radius dummy
!
aaa authentication login eap_methods group rad_eap
aaa authentication login mac_methods local
aaa authorization ipmobile default group rad_pmip 
aaa accounting network acct_methods start-stop group rad_acct
!
!
aaa session-id common
clock timezone PCTime 3
clock summer-time PCTime date Mar 30 2003 2:00 Oct 26 2003 3:00
!
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-1766803642
 enrollment selfsigned
 subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-1766803642
 revocation-check none
 rsakeypair TP-self-signed-1766803642
!
!
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-1766803642
 certificate self-signed 01
  39820251 308201BA A0030201 02020101 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 04050030 
  31312F30 2D060355 04031326 494F532D 53656C66 2D536967 6E65642D 43657274 
  69666963 6174652D 31373636 38303336 3432301E 170D3032 30333038 32303533 
  34355A17 0D323030 31303130 30303030 305A3031 312F302D 06035504 03132649 
  4F532D53 656C662D 5369676E 65642D43 65727469 66696361 74652D31 37363638 
  30333634 3230819F 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 01050003 818D0030 81890281 
  8100BC6F 40629690 5287E7F1 42FC08BD 2A6DF927 8B32FFF7 26487B33 9798814A 
  B1E9A95D A6F773D4 101739D3 AD93D9C1 BB943C19 D5D38650 DCE3DF91 C5E8FC4F 
  AFF4AFC1 1E86BC13 1254505B 1EC1208A 426ACFDB 390D14CE 749ED9E7 C6A7DA28 
  7A532215 C32FF50D BA11D6E4 4DFA0E0D 04F743EB E3D35837 CB952F09 BDE58B07 
  6B290203 010001A3 68307730 0F060355 1D130101 FF040530 030101FF 30240603 
  551D1104 1D301B82 196D7972 6F757465 722E706C 61787573 2D707269 6D652E6E 
  6574301F 0603551D 23041830 168014DA CC75AC6C 050CC055 E30CC3DD 3BAC23F1 
  8CA8F530 1D060355 1D0E0416 0414DACC 75AC6C05 0CC055E3 0CC3DD3B AC23F18C 
  A8F5300D 06092A86 4886F70D 01010405 00038181 00721619 BCBC2E4D E326FC0E 
  C1E956A1 A9DA5F8C 9C2E1D42 D893D006 1A93596E D6306E51 767461AC D16CBC7C 
  F43BCBA4 00302A5E 5AB5F02E 225172BC 7520F487 13232D9C FFCA0DBB D34059EC 
  4407F16B 0460D75C F7A414DE 058E8A1F 18BBBF3D 2E352016 89185F40 68845A96 
  A6117289 14176336 E189E29C 88DF6314 08C2E5DB 7D
    quit
dot11 syslog
!
dot11 ssid c877
   vlan 1
   authentication open 
   authentication key-management wpa
   guest-mode
   wpa-psk ascii 7 030F510A51577066662D
!
no ip source-route
ip cef
no ip dhcp use vrf connected
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.10.10.1
!
ip dhcp pool sdm-pool1
   import all
   network 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
   dns-server 88.147.128.17 88.147.128.16 
   default-router 10.10.10.1 
!
!
ip auth-proxy max-nodata-conns 3
ip admission max-nodata-conns 3
no ip bootp server
ip name-server 88.147.129.15
ip name-server 88.147.129.16
!
!
!
username admin password 7 0100570A0A18125C331C1E48
! 
!
archive
 log config
  hidekeys
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 10
ip ssh time-out 60
ip ssh authentication-retries 2
!
bridge irb
!
!
interface ATM0
 no ip address
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip route-cache flow
 no atm ilmi-keepalive
 dsl operating-mode auto 
!
interface ATM0.1 point-to-point
 description $ES_WAN$$FW_OUTSIDE$
 pvc 0/33 
  pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1
 !
!
interface ATM0.2 multipoint
!
interface FastEthernet0
!
interface FastEthernet1
!
interface FastEthernet2
!
interface FastEthernet3
!
interface Dot11Radio0
 no ip address
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip virtual-reassembly
 ip route-cache flow
 !
 !
 encryption vlan 1 mode ciphers aes-ccm 
 !
 broadcast-key vlan 2 change 45
 !
 !
 ssid c877
 !
 speed basic-1.0 basic-2.0 basic-5.5 6.0 9.0 basic-11.0 12.0 18.0 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0
 power client 17
 channel 2442
 station-role root
 no cdp enable
!
interface Dot11Radio0.1
 encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
 ip virtual-reassembly
 no cdp enable
 bridge-group 1
 bridge-group 1 subscriber-loop-control
 bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
 bridge-group 1 block-unknown-source
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning
 no bridge-group 1 unicast-flooding
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip virtual-reassembly
 bridge-group 1
!
interface Dialer0
 ip address negotiated
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip mtu 1452
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 encapsulation ppp
 ip route-cache flow
 dialer pool 1
 dialer-group 1
 no cdp enable
 ppp authentication chap pap callin
 ppp chap hostname jdsl10252
 ppp chap password 7 1214040406471E00387B2D1B
 ppp pap sent-username jdsl10252 password 7 1043080A1133900F1E54231E
!
interface BVI1
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
!
ip forward-protocol nd
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer0
!
ip http server
ip http access-class 23
ip http secure-server
ip http timeout-policy idle 60 life 86400 requests 10000
ip nat inside source list 100 interface Dialer0 overload
ip nat inside source static tcp 10.10.10.102 25 interface Dialer0 25
ip nat inside source static tcp 10.10.10.103 12345 interface Dialer0 12345
ip nat inside source static tcp 10.10.10.101 3389 interface Dialer0 3389
ip nat inside source static tcp 10.11.11.188 22 interface Dialer0 22
ip nat inside source static udp 10.11.11.188 1701 interface Dialer0 1701
ip nat inside source static udp 10.11.11.188 500 interface Dialer0 500
ip nat inside source static udp 10.11.11.188 4500 interface Dialer0 4500
ip nat inside source static tcp 10.11.11.188 5925 interface Dialer0 5925
ip nat inside source static tcp 10.11.11.201 80 interface Dialer0 80
!
logging trap debugging
logging 10.10.10.102
snmp-server community publi RO
snmp-server community public RO 99
no cdp run
!
!
radius-server attribute 32 include-in-access-req format %h
radius-server host 127.0.0.1 auth-port 1645 acct-port 1646 key 7 150A1314
radius-server vsa send accounting
!
control-plane
!
bridge 1 protocol ieee
bridge 1 route ip
banner exec ^C
% Password expiration warning.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Cisco Router and Security Device Manager (SDM) is installed on this device and 
it provides the default username "cisco" for  one-time use. If you have already 
used the username "cisco" to login to the router and your IOS image supports the 
"one-time" user option, then this username has already expired. You will not be 
able to login to the router with this username after you exit this session.
 
It is strongly suggested that you create a new username with a privilege level 
of 15 using the following command.
 
username <myuser> privilege 15 secret 0 <mypassword>
 
Replace <myuser> and <mypassword> with the username and password you want to 
use.
 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
^C
banner login ^CAuthorized access only!
 Disconnect IMMEDIATELY if you are not an authorized user!^C
!
line con 0
 password 7 010B1E1C
 no modem enable
 transport output telnet
line aux 0
 transport output telnet
line vty 0 4
 privilege level 15
 password 7 073C72425A1B002105420297
 transport input telnet ssh
!
scheduler max-task-time 5000
scheduler allocate 4000 1000
scheduler interval 500
end
```

Comment: c wifi клиента traceroute останавливается на  10.10.10.1

Answer (score 0):

артефакт: проблема была в source list